# Concatenate the first letters of each word of the string without spaces

Tags: java, string, character

Given a string, get first letter of every word and return the result as a string without spaces.

```java
public class Solution {
    static String getFirstLetterWord(String text) {
        char[] c = text.toCharArray();
        String output = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i] != ' ' && (i == 0 || c[i - 1] != ' ')) {
                System.out.println(c[i]);
                output = output + c[i];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string by space `text.split(" ")` it will give you an array of words,
you can later loop over the array and get the first character of each word and combine then into an array

Example

```java
static String getFirstLetterWord(String text) {
    final String[] words = text.split(" ");
    String output = "";
    for (String word : words) {
        output += word.charAt(0);
    }
    return output;
}
```

For better performance you can use a StringBuilder

Example

```java
static String getFirstLetterWord(String text) {
    final String[] words = text.split(" ");
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        output.append(word.charAt(0));
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Or if you're using java 8 you can do it with streams

```java
static String getFirstLetterWord(String text) {
    final String[] words = text.split(" ");
    return  Stream.of(words).map(word -> word.subSequence(0, 1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```